# Query to get the product that has special price with from and to date

Tags: magento2, sql

create a SQL query for getting product's sku which does have special price from and to date[image: these From and to Date]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one using subquery:

```
SELECT catprod.entity_id,catprod.value,catprod.value_id,catprod.store_id,
catprod.attribute_id,(SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal 
WHERE attribute_id=78 AND entity_id=catprod.entity_id) AS 
special_price FROM
 catalog_product_entity_decimal AS catprod WHERE attribute_id = 77;
```

> Result is : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOilc.png

Comment: Thank you,

Need special price's  from and to date data...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one,

> SELECT cpe.sku as sku,cped.value as special_price FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal as cped join catalog_product_entity as cpe on cped.row_id=cpe.entity_id
> WHERE attribute_id=(SELECT `attribute_id`  FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'special_price');

Answer (score 0):

*query for getting product's sku which does have special price from and to date*

In B2B we can get by using the following Query,

```
select  catalog_product_entity.sku,catalog_product_entity_datetime.value from catalog_product_entity 
JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime ON catalog_product_entity.row_id = catalog_product_entity_datetime.row_id;
```

[image: Response]

**for Magento Open Source may differs**